# round up this way (keeping up to decimal)

Tags: java, math, rounding

How do i change 2.278481... to 2.2?

```
double a = 180;
double b = 79;
double x = (a/b);
```

`Math.ceil()` returns `3` and `Math.floor()` returns `2`

Comment: Do you only 1 digit in floating point?

Comment: You want to print it?

Comment: @SathishKumarJ yes!

Comment: @VatsalSura i want to keep 1 digit from floating. I can print it later

Comment: If you only want 1 decimal place, multiply the value by 10, convert to an Int, then divide by 10 to a double.

Comment: Use _DecimalFormat_

Comment: @RichardGoodman great and simple! thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just set the setMaximumFractionDigits to 1. Like this:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(format(14.0184849945)); // prints '14.0'
    System.out.println(format(13)); // prints '13'
    System.out.println(format(3.5)); // prints '3.5'
    System.out.println(format(3.138136)); // prints '3.1'
}

 public static String format(Number n) {
    NumberFormat format = DecimalFormat.getInstance();
    format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);
    format.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
    format.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);
    return format.format(n);
 }

}
```

This may helps you